# Get public post from Facebook's Graph Search API 2.x with Facebook SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK for .NET and I want to do a public post search (hashtag search).
I noted that Facebook API 2.x doesn't allow post search and I'm getting this error(OAuthException).
(#11) Post search has been deprecated

Is there any alternative/solution anther than using Facebook API 1.x to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the Public Post Search is deprecated. There is no alternative solution for this, they wouldn´t have deprecated it if they would have added another possibility.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog